# Problemas com exibir um dado de uma array

Tags: php, sql, array, sql-server

Sou novo no stackOverflow, por mas que eu use a plataforma para cessar minhas dúvidas direto, nunca tinha feito uma conta. Enfim, estou com um problema atípico com um código PHP. Estou fazendo uma consulta ao banco de dados(diretamente do phpmyadmin no xammp), que como podem ver no código abaixo retorna justamente oque eu quero:

```
SELECT sum(cha_valor) as 'valorTotal' FROM chamadas WHERE cha_nome_funcionario = 'José Garcia Pinto'
return = 148.00
```

Esse valor é o correto. Então sabendo do retorno do valor certo vamos para o código PHP.

```
<?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_employee";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>
data.addRows([

    <?php

        while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

     ?>

      ['<?php echo $dados['user_nome'] ?>', 
      <?php $sql = "SELECT sum(cha_valor) FROM chamadas WHERE cha_nome_funcionario = '" . $dados['user_nome'] . "'"; 
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
            echo $result[0];?>],

    <?php }; ?>
```

Estou usando uma API de criação de gráficos, GOOGLECHARTS. Estou fazendo um gráfico que mostra duas informações, o nome do usuário e, onde está dando o problema, a quantidade de dinheiro que ele rendeu(que está armazenada no banco).
   O erro ocorre por conta de eu não conseguir printar na tela o resultado(que um deles era pra ser 148 como mostrei o retorno pra vocês), ao usar esse echo $result[0], ele dá um erro que a variável está vazia ou seja não existe valor para esse índice. Se eu tento usar o índice em string usando aspas simples('cha_chamada') ele dá o mesmo erro. Se eu tento usar somente o $result, ele dá o erro notice-array-to-string-conversion.
   Enfim, não sei o que fazer mais! Quando coloco o $result no var_dump(), aparece isso:

```
array(1) { ["sum(cha_valor)"]=> string(6) "148.00" }
```

Ou seja, presumo que o valor esteja retornando correto, como no próprio PHPMyAdmin, porém não consigo exibir o valor para usar no gráfico.
   O Projeto está no meu github e é muito fácil fazer os preparativos e começar a codificar.
   Se quiserem entra pra ver todo o código do problema, só entrarem nesse link do github https://github.com/FeCesar/Order_of_service_system e entrarem no diretório(admin/index.php) do problema que estará comentado bem no começo da página.
   Espero que alguém possa me dar uma luz! Obrigado desde já!

Comment: troque `$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);` por [`$result = mysqli_fetch_row($query);`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `mysqli_fetch_assoc` cria uma array onde o chave é o nome da coluna. Suas queries são diferentes, na primeira utiliza `as 'valorTotal'`, já no PHP não.

---

Supondo que utilize o `as 'valorTotal'`:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(cha_valor) as `valorTotal` FROM chamadas WHERE cha_nome_funcionario = '" . $dados['user_nome'] . "'";
```

Bastaria trocar o `$result[0]` por `$result['valorTotal']`.

---

```
        $sql = "SELECT sum(cha_valor) as `valorTotal` FROM chamadas WHERE cha_nome_funcionario = '" . $dados['user_nome'] . "'"; 
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
        echo $result['valorTotal'];
```

---

Se prefere acessar os valores usando `$result[0]`, você deverá utilizar o [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado! Tentei de tudo, não imaginava que seria tão simples resolver... Estranho que no final, mesmo trazendo a informação com o `mysqli_fetch_row()`, e a informação sendo do tipo inteiro, tive que converter para inteiro quando printei ela na tela. Por fim ficou assim o código. `<?php $sqlDinheiro = "SELECT sum(cha_valor) FROM chamadas WHERE cha_nome_funcionario = '" . $dados['user_nome'] . "'"; $queryDinheiro = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlDinheiro); $dinheiro = mysqli_fetch_row($queryDinheiro); echo (int)$dinheiro[0];`